# What release of Ng-zorro-mobile i must use with angular 5

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I'am looking of a release of **Ng-zorro-mobile** i must use with angular 5. 
I' using **Ionic 3** with **angular 5** Help please

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to upgrade your dependencies. The oldest version history they have reads that the lowest Angular version they've supported is 6.x.

https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd-mobile/blob/0.9.4/package.json